# Spring ManyToMany hide object fields

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many

I'm new at spring development and I made sample project to understand this framework better. I have a entity `User` and also have `@ManyToMany` relationship with same `User` object (see code snippet)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Item implements Serializable {

    /*
        Other entity properties...
    */

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="candidate",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="itemId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="candidateItemId")})
    private List<Item> candidateItems;

    public List<Item> getCandidateItems() {
        return candidateItems;
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected however I want to hide `candidateItems` on my inner objects (for those objects that are in `candidateItems`  array (see `json`))

```
{
    "createdAt": 1520374599000,
    "updatedAt": 1520374600000,
    "candidateItems": [
        {
            "createdAt": 1520374599000,
            "updatedAt": 1520374600000,
            "candidateItems": [] // <-------------- no need this!!!
        },
        {
            "createdAt": 1520374599000,
            "updatedAt": 1520374600000,
            "candidateItems": [] // <-------------- no need this!!!
        }
    ]
}
```

So is it possible to do that? Or I need to create other entity with same fields except `candidateItems`?

Comment: Have you tried @Transient annotation ?

Comment: My advice would be to stop using your persistence model to communicate with the outside world. Design your APIs. Design your persistence. Don't use the same classes for both. Create a separate class to represent an Item as returned by your API.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to do this without creating new entity?